# Hibernate Search and composed key using @IdClass

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a problem to integrate Hibernate Search in existing project with hundreds of entities but at least half of entities use @IdClass annotation as composed key. Can I solve the problem using the annotation @IdClass?

I also read this post [Hibernate search and composed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796497/hibernate-search-does-not-work-woth-composite-primary-key-using-idclass/)but I have not managed to solve my problem.

I have the following example:

entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FAKVS_DB")
@IdClass(value=PK_FAKVS_DB.class)
@Audited
@Indexed
public class FAKVS_DB implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @Column(name="Key_FAM", length=10, nullable=false)l
   private String keyFam;

   @Id
   @Column(name="Komponentennr", nullable=false)
   private Integer komponentenNr;

  @Id
  @Column(name="Hinweis", nullable=true, length=4)
  private String hinweis;

  //getters and setters
}
```

and composed key:

```
public class PK_FAKVS_DB implements Serializable {

   private String keyFam;
   private Integer komponentenNr;
   private String hinweis;

   //getters and setters
 }
```

The error that occurs is:

```
HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000212: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was transforming identifiers to Lucene Documents
java.lang.ClassCastException: package.entities.module.fi.pk.PK_FAKVS_DB cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:63)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1995)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1966)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1901)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
```

If I can not use @IdClass annotation can you tell me what are the alternatives?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to add a new property to be used as *Id* by Hibernate Search. You can mark this with `@DocumentId` to have the Hibernate Search engine treat the alternative property as the identifier in the index.

You will need to ensure that this new property is unique of course; this can typically done by generating a `String` from the real id. You probably want to annotate the new getter with `@Transient` so that it doesn't get persisted in the database.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply @Sanne. I saw that you work as project lead for Hibernate Search. Any idea if in the near future Hibernate Search will work(accept) also with "@IdClass" annotation?